# Share Pricebook record to the current user using Apex trigger or class or Flow

Tags: apex, sharing, user, pricebook, apex-sharing

If there any Option to share the newly created Pricebook using Apex class to Current user.
We have separate object(Opportunity Share) for Opportunity sharing like that do we have any object to share the pricebook to current user?.

If No, please suggest me how to share the created pricebook record to current user.

We maintaining OWD setting for Pricebook is "View Only".

Answer (score 1):

You can share using a Trigger and Apex based Sharing rules to run on create of a Pricebook, see here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm

Comment: You should include the essential information in your answer; if the link ever becomes invalid, this answer would become worthless for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for your response
I don't want to share the all pricebook to current user.
Just I need to share the single procebook record which was created by the current user using flow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we cannot create Sharing records like any other Standard or Custom Object, there are some open ideas about this thing.

There is no Pricebook2Share Object to write on.